# Rspec error on Cent OS 4.8 and rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I use "spec xxx.rb" to test certain ruby code, I got this error:

```
Missing these required gems:
  webrat  ~> 0.4.4

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.174 at /usr/local/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.5 at /root/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

And I have webrat 0.5.3 gem running already. Here's my server environment:

Operating System: CentOS 4.8 
Ruby 1.8.7 i686-linux 
Rails 2.3.4

and gem list:
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
actionmailer (2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.2, 2.0.2)
actionpack (2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.2, 2.0.2)
activerecord (2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.2, 2.0.2)
activeresource (2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.2, 2.0.2)
activesupport (2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.2, 2.0.2)
builder (2.1.2)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
cucumber (0.3.104)
daemons (1.0.10)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
fastthread (1.0.7)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
git (1.2.3, 1.2.2)
mongrel (1.1.5)
mongrel_cluster (1.0.5)
nokogiri (1.3.3)
passenger (2.2.5)
polyglot (0.2.9)
rack (1.0.0)
radiant (0.8.1)
rails (2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.2.2, 2.0.2)
rake (0.8.7, 0.8.4, 0.8.1)
RedCloth (4.2.2)
rmagick (2.11.1)
rspec (1.2.8)
rspec-rails (1.2.7.1)
sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5)
term-ansicolor (1.0.4)
treetop (1.4.2)
webrat (0.5.3)
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that version of Webrat is incompatible with your version of rspec. Try installing that specific version as such:

```
sudo gem install webrat --version "=0.4.4"
```

Comment: I tried, but same error. I think by running this command the webrat in use will still be 0.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Man!! hit the same problem (luckily figured this one out!)

You are probably using radiant and its quite likely that you have config/environments/test.rb saying:

```
config.gem "webrat", :version => "~>0.4.4", :lib => false
```

Remove the `version => "~>0.4.4",` and its starts working.